# Is it better practice to pass a variable to a prototype or reference a property inside the function?

Tags: javascript

I understand that functions should be self-contained on account of readability and code-recycling.

However, does this rule still hold true for functions which are in fact a part of an object prototype?

Should I prefer to pass in a variable to a prototype method when I can just directly access that value as a property from inside the object using `this`?

Comment: `this` is also passed when you call the function.

Comment: That's exactly what `this` is made for. It would be weird not to use it - if you don't use instance attributes, you don't need instances or prototypes either but can just go for static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **perfectly acceptable and common practice to access instance attributes** from methods defined higher up the prototype chain, e.g.:

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name; 
};
Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
}

var alex = new Person('Alex');
console.log(alex.getName());
```

In this example, calling `getName()` without the right context would not work as expected.

Also refer to [the MDN page on `Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), where this pattern is used a lot in their examples.

Comment: Are there any specific limitations or standards for interweaving object properties within itself? And should I be documenting all the inter-dependencies?